# Changing user password in LDAP using C# LdapConnection Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I am using a C# client to connect to an OpenLDAP instance.

I need to verify that the user has input the correct old password. If that verification succeeds, I need to update their "userPassword" attribute with a new password.

I keep getting `DirectoryOperationException: A value in the request is invalid.` Here's the code:

```
public static void UpdateUserPassword(ref UserProfile user, string oldPassword, string newPassword) {

        string connAccountName = ControllerHelper.GetProperty("VSP_SECURITY_PRINCIPAL", true);
        string connAccountPassword = ControllerHelper.GetProperty("VSP_SECURITY_CREDENTIALS", true);

        int myConnectionId;
        LdapConnection ldapConnection;
        lock (_sConnectionTable.SyncRoot) {
            myConnectionId = _getFirstOpenConnectionId();
            ldapConnection = _getConnectionFromPool(ref myConnectionId);//check for null
        }


        try {

            /*Here is where I try to validate the user's old password*/
            ldapConnection.Bind(new NetworkCredential(user.dnName, oldPassword));

            ModifyRequest request = new ModifyRequest(
                    user.dnName,
                    DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace,
                    "userPassword",
                    newPassword

                );

            ModifyResponse modResponse = (ModifyResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(request);

            user.state.successMsg = "Yay it worked!";

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            user.state.errorMsg = e.Message;

        }
        finally {
            _releaseConnectionToPool(myConnectionId);
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you debug can you tell exactly which line is throwing the exception - is it the validate line, or the change password line?

Answer (score 1):

I think the last param of ModifyRequest in the ctor you are using expecting an object array and you are only passing a single value which  is probably causing your error.

I'd use this instead of your ModifyRequest line

```
DirectoryAttributeModification modifyUserPassword = new DirectoryAttributeModification();
modifyUserPassword.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace;
modifyUserPassword.Name = "userPassword";
modifyUserPassword.Add(newPassword);

ModifyRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(user.dnName, modifyUserPassword);
```

Comment: actually, the ModifyRequest constructor accepts "params object[] values", so the single value is converted to an array.  That is also how i use it.

Answer (score -1):

in .NET framework 3.5 and higher you can use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement which will greatly simplify things.
the example below might solve your problem

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
        user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
        user.UnlockAccount();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that API was only for active directory? I'm connecting to an OpenLDAP instance.

Comment: actually it doesn't work very well outside AD. but i've previously successfully implemented some cases with OpenLDAP. so it's better to use System.DirectoryServices.Protocols